# Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom: why is numpy displaying a wrong solution while scipy isn't?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I've written up a piece of code to solve the 1-dimensional Schrodinger equation. While the numpy.linalg.eig() routine has been working fine for the harmonic oscillator, it seems to add one spurious solution for the Coulomb potential. On the other hand Scipy's sparse.linalg.eigsh() appears to do well. Here is my script:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.sparse import diags
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh

N = 500
x0 = 8
xMin, xMax = -x0, x0
xstep = (xMax - xMin) / (N - 1)
x = np.linspace(xMin, xMax, N)

k = np.array([np.ones(N-1),-2*np.ones(N),np.ones(N-1)])
offset = [-1,0,1]
Lapl = diags(k,offset).toarray() / (xstep**2)
T = -Lapl *.5

V = -1./(np.abs(x)) #Coulomb
#V = .5 * x**2 #HO

H = T.copy()
for i in range(N):
    H[i,i] += V[i]

#vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(H)
vals, vecs = eigsh(H, which='SM')
idx = vals.argsort()[::1]
vals, vecs = vals[idx], vecs[:,idx]

#exact solution
Hatom = (np.pi)**(-1./2) * np.exp(- np.abs(x)) * np.abs(x) * np.sqrt(4 * np.pi)
norm = np.sum(Hatom**2)
Hatom = Hatom / np.sqrt(norm)

#numerical solution
GS = vecs[:,0] #0th is the gs if using sp's eigsh, but is spurious if using np.linalg.eig
normGS = np.sum(GS**2)
GS = GS / np.sqrt(normGS)

plt.plot(x, Hatom**2, label = 'exact')
plt.plot(x, GS**2, label = 'numeric')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print( np.round(vals[:10], 4) )
```

which yields the following plots (I'm also having trouble showing the pictures directly here, sorry about that!):

- Using numpy:[np_0th_eigenvector_spurious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFnPS.png)
  & [np_1th_eigenvector_gs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8qde.png)
- Using scipy: [sp_gs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8jc0.png)

I'd expect this to come from a different handling of the singularity of the Coulomb potential (though I chose an even number of points to avoid x = 0), since both numpy and scipy work fine for the harmonic oscillator and Morse potential (not reproduced here for brevity). Yet this makes tricky how to handle arbitrary potentials!

What's more, the eigenvalues for the Coulomb potential land pretty far from the 1/n^2 sequence (the lowest one comes from using numpy):

```
 vals: [-15.220171  -0.500363  -0.331042  -0.085621  -0.02475    0.242598
   0.344308   0.741555   0.885751   1.402606]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Does numpy/scipy contains a routine I could use safely to solve the eigenvalue problem, regardless of the potential?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It‘s late, and I have no time now to look into this today. But I would be interested how numpy.linalg.eigh would perform?

Answer (score 5):

The argument `which='SM'` in [`eigsh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html) tells the function to find the `k` eigenvalues with the smallest *magnitude*.  The most negative eigenvalue is about -15.22, but this will not be included in the results of `eigsh`, because there are many other positive and negative eigenvalues with magnitudes less than 15.22.  If you want to compare the results to those of [`numpy.linalg.eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) (or better, [`numpy.linalg.eigh`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html)), use `which='SA'`.  That tells `eigsh` to find the algebraically smallest values.  If you do that, then the `vals` that you compute with `eigsh` will agree with the first 6 eigenvalues computed by `numpy.linalg.eigh`.

After making this change, you'll have to change the selection of the numerically computed eigenvector to be plotted to

```
GS = vecs[:,1]
```

to have the plots of the exact and numerical results agree.

Answer (score 1):

Following what @Warren said about `which` k eigenvectors and eigenvalues to find, you can also take profit of the **tridiagonal** structure of matrix `H`,  by using [scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal.html#scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal) here instead of just `np.linalg.eigh` which gives you :

```
from scipy.linalg import eigh_tridiagonal
d = np.diag(H)
e = np.diag(H,k=1)
vals, vecs = eigh_tridiagonal(d,e)
idx = vals.argsort()[::1]
vals, vecs = vals[idx], vecs[:,idx]
```

and select accordingly `GS = vecs[:,1]` to get the same results with 2 times faster computation :

```
%timeit scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal(d,e)
>>> 10.7 ms ± 37.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit numpy.linalg.eigh(H)
>>> 19.4 ms ± 28.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(H, which='SA')
>>> 115 ms ± 1.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```